# Есть программа для перевода текста в верхний регистр с выводом результата с помощью функции DrawText. Как изменить ее и сделать вывод в LISTBOX?

Tags: c++, winapi

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK BtnProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    static LPCWSTR szAppName = TEXT("MyWindowApp");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass;                      // Структура настройки класса

    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);       // Размер структуры
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; // Cтиль окна (перекрашивать при изменении размера)
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;           // Указатель для callback
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;                  // Количество дополнительных байт windowinstance
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;           // Хэндл окна
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    wndclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(nullptr, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);               // Регистрация класса окна

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Лабораторная работа №2"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);               // Показать окно
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);                       // Перекрасить окно

    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}


TCHAR*  ToUpperCase(TCHAR *input) {
    static TCHAR buffer[1000];
    TCHAR *s = input;
    TCHAR *t = buffer;

    while (*s != '\0') {
        *t = toupper(*s);
        s++;
        t++;
    }
    return buffer;
}


HWND editHwnd;
HMENU editIdentifier = (HMENU)10000;
TCHAR string[100];
TCHAR* upperString = nullptr;
WNDPROC OldBtnProc;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
    // Cообщения обработки
    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        editHwnd = CreateWindow(
            L"EDIT",     // Предопределенный класс (+юникод)
            L"",         // Текст поля ввода (пусто) 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP,  // Стили 
            100,         // x (абсцисса)  
            100,         // y (ордината)
            400,         // Ширина поля
            25,          // Высота поля
            hwnd,        // Родительское окно
            editIdentifier,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);       // Указатель не требуется

        // Подкласс кнопки управления
        OldBtnProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            SetWindowLongPtr(editHwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC,
                reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(BtnProc))));

        // Сохранить оригинал, кнопка оконной процедуры по умолчанию в качестве
        // кнопки управления пользовательскими данными
        SetWindowLongPtr(editHwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(OldBtnProc));
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        if (upperString != nullptr) {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            DrawText(hdc, upperString, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK BtnProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Оконная процедура подкласса для кнопки
    static HWND hEdit;
    // Восстановить ранее сохраненную кнопку процедуры окна 
    static WNDPROC OrigBtnProc = reinterpret_cast<WNDPROC>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
        GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA)));
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_RETURN:
            GetWindowText(editHwnd, string, 100);
            upperString = ToUpperCase(string);
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);
            break;
        }

    default:
        // Вызов хэндла по умолчанию для управления процессом
        return CallWindowProc(OrigBtnProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Буду крайне благодарен за помощь (:

Comment: Выкладывайте код в тело поста - если с pastebin код удалится, для дальнейших посетителей ваш вопрос будет бесполезен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На этом сайте не делают лабораторные за студентов, поэтому приведу только часть кода, отвечающую за создание и добавление строки в ListBox.

Вот так мы создаем ListBox, который будет содержать строки:

```
hListBox = CreateWindow(TEXT("listbox"), NULL, 
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD | LBS_HASSTRINGS,
                        7, 35, 300, 200,
                        hWnd, (HMENU)(1),
                        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);
```

А вот так мы добавляем строку в ListBox:

```
TCHAR string[] = TEXT("просто строка для примера");
SendMessage(hListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, NULL, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(string));
```

Дальше, надеюсь, вы уже и сами разберетесь, если еще возникнут вопросы, спрашивайте.